# Python Bottle rest headers not working with underscore

Tags: python, rest, mod-wsgi, bottle, request-headers

I am facing issues for rest headers with underscore, not getting the rest headers value while i am printing them.

Did someone have any idea of how I could make this work ?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use underscores in headers.  Even if it used to work, you should stop.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use underscores in header names, use only dashes as separators.

Mainstream web servers such as Apache and nginx, plus some Python WSGI servers/frameworks will throw away headers with underscores to avoid header spoofing.

Imagine you have a header:

```
My-Header: value
```

This in CGI/WSGI gets converted to variable:

```
HTTP_MY_HEADER: value
```

when passed to application.

The problem is that a header:

```
My_Header: value
```

also maps to the same.

The danger here is that a client could use one, and something between such as a proxy could deliberately set the other to try and take precedence, overwriting the original when the server/application processes it.

As this is a potential security issue, servers are only allowing headers with alphanumerics and dashes to pass through now and anything else is discarded.

Comment: Hi Graham,
But it has been working since couple of months,suddenly it stops working i can't change it for now because this change also be applied to client side as well.

Comment: What WSGI server are you using? Was the WSGI server recently upgraded?

Comment: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured.

Comment: I have three applications with same settings, one is running good, while two has facing the underscore issue for headers.

Comment: Are the ones which work using Apache 2.2? If so that is the reason. Apache 2.4 blocks those headers. More recent versions of mod_wsgi will block them as well even if using Apache 2.2 still.

Comment: But i am little bit confuse here from the third application behavior, two are not working and one is working under same configuration. @Graham this may be issue for the pyc files that already compiled from Apache 2.2 or something else. Because i have not put any changes in the third application. May be that's reason it is working yet for now.

Comment: Nothing to do with ``pyc`` files. Are some of the servers (the working ones) using Apache 2.2 for mod_wsgi or not. The blocking is done in Apache not in Python.

Comment: Even I was using _ on bjoern server, things were working find and suddenly things stopped working one day. The cause was _ in header. Had to replace it with hyphen